# using dajaxice with django_tables2

Tags: ajax, django, dajaxice, django-tables2

I have a django table and I use dajaxice to refresh the table . I use pagination to show 20 rows of data on each page. My problem is when a user is on page two after the ajax has refreshed the table, they still only see page one.

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

```
from django_tables2   import RequestConfig
from meli.tables import MelliTable
def index2(request):
    table1 = MelliTable(ModelMelli2.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 20}).configure(table1)
    return render(request, 'meli/index1.html', {'table1': table1 })
#ajax file
def refresh(request):
    table1 = MelliTable(ModelMelli2.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 20}).configure(table1)
    table = render_to_string('meli/djax.html', {'table1': table1 })
    return simplejson.dumps({'table':table})
```